# How to create file inside container docker-compose with java

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, containers

I try to create a file with java using docker-compose container by making a binding between a host directory and a directory in the container but it doesn't work.

My docker-compose.yml is :

`version: '3'
services:
  buildbox:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/buildbox/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/data
      - $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2
      - temp_dir:/data/flow
  service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-local
    env_file:
      - docker/loc.env
    image: flow:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "5005:5005"
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend.group.name=services"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.docker.localhost"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
      - "traefik.port=8081"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
    networks:
      - traefik
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: docker-commons_traefik
volumes:
  temp_dir:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       type: none
      device:/home/my-user/dev/flow/tmp
      o: bind`

can someone tell me what it's wrong ?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what actually happens?  Do you get an error message of some sort?  Is there application code that's relevant to the example?

Comment: @DavidMaze the volume is created fine, but when i start application (docker-compose up --build) i get errors like the file which is supposed to be created it cannot find it in the path (/home/my-user/dev/flow/tmp)

Comment: Usually you should have mounted that volume in the docker before you start the docker. So I assume the path you are writing to is hosted as volume